# ActionScript 2.0 List Component - Change pointer icon to hand for list items

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, actionscript-2, flash-cs3

I am working on an older Flash project created in CS3 ActionScript 2.0 How can I make the pointer cursor change to the hand when hover over a list item?

```
_root.slidePanel.myList
```

'myList' is the list. I have traced out the contents of the List MC and it has a child MC called 'content_mc'. I assumed this was the object containing all of my list items but the only members of this MC I can see (when tracing them out) are 'setRGB' and 'searchKey'.

Can someone offer some help?

Comment: Do you mean the default angled cursor (default) turn to the hand cursor with the finger pointing (pointer), or the hand cursor with the finger pointing (pointer) turn to the open-hand cursor (move on Mac)?

Comment: I mean change the 'arrow' to a 'pointing hand' - I believe the first thing you described. Just like you would expect when hovering over a link.

Comment: this shouldn't be tagged "actionscript-3".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure about AS2, but this should work in AS3. If you don't want AS3 answers, you may want to untag 'actionscript-3'

To get a custom cursor you'll need to attach `MouseEvent.MOUSE_ENTER` and `MouseEvent.MOUSE_LEAVE` to whatever it is you want to have the custom cursor.

```
function mouseEntered(e:MouseEvent):void
{
 Mouse.hide();
 stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVE, moveCursor);
 //create mouse cursor and add to stage
}

function mouseLeft(e:MouseEvent):void
{
 Mouse.show();
 stage.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVE, moveCursor);
 //remove mouse cursor from stage
}

function moveCursor(e:MouseEvent):void
{
 // move the mouse cursor to wherever the mouse is.
}
```

This is one way of handling a custom cursor. You'll need to design a cursor that can be moved around the stage as the mouse is moved.

EDIT to add:
In AS3, `Sprites` have a property: `useHandCursor` that can be set to true to show the pointer when hovered over.

Comment: Ouch.. I wasn't expecting that I would have to design my own pointer. I assumed that I could make the list items behave like a link.

Comment: @Nick if useHandCursor works, you wont have to design your own.

Comment: So your above solution would work. AS2 does not have useHandCursor property it would appear.